# Plot an interactive ggplotly plot via shiny (currently produces an empty plot)

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I have problems generating a window where one can select one out of a list of interactive plots to be displaied. Currently, the result is a window with the selection sidebar but an empty plot in the main window.
The code I put together from parts I've found on the internet is as follows:

```
ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel(h1(textOutput("XRD-Ergebnisse"))),
  sidebarPanel(
    uiOutput("filter_degree"), width = 2
  ),
  mainPanel = mainPanel(
    h3(textOutput("Diffraction Pattern")),
    plotlyOutput("plot")
  )
)
#server.r
server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$filter_degree <- renderUI({
    radioButtons("rd", "Select Option", choices = str_replace(files, ".xy", ""),
                 selected = "AH1Y")
  })
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    plot <- html[which(str_replace(files, ".xy", "") == input$rd)]
    })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

and I've loaded the following packages:

```
c("powdR", "ggplot2", "stringr", "tools", "readxl", "dplyr", "shiny", "plotly")
```

of which the first ones were used to create the variable `html`, which is a large `list()` of interactive plots that are output of functions of the `powdR` package and, according to the respective documentation, `ggplotly` plots. This is why I used `plotlyOutput` instead of `plotOutput`. The plots themselves have two panels and a legend each and are interactive (posting the complete data and script to get the plots would be too much, I guess).

Unfortunately, despite trying for hours I haven't got any useful results. I hope the error is obvious to more advanced Shiny users than I am (i.e. to not absolute beginners).

Notes: `str_replace(...)` here produces only a character vector with strings equal to the names of the list (html), of which "AH1Y" is one option (here the one to be preselected).

Edit: For the definition of the object `html`

```
html <- list()
for(i in 1:NROW(results)){
  html[[i]] <- plot(results[[i]], wavelength = "Cu", interactive = TRUE, mode = "both", main = str_replace(files[[i]], ".xy", ""))
}
names(html) <- str_replace(files, ".xy", "")
```

Which gives a large list object. This object, however, is not accessible as `html[[x]]` but as `html[x]` (for reasons I don't know). Running just `html[x]` in R studio plots the `x`th graph to the *viewer* panel. The `[[x]]` call only produces an error message:

```
Warning: Error in [[: subscript out of bounds
  [No stack trace available]
```

Edit #2: When I try to use the non-interactive version and manually `ggplotly()` it, I get:

```
Warning messages:
1: In geom2trace.default(dots[[1L]][[1L]], dots[[2L]][[1L]], dots[[3L]][[1L]]) :
  geom_GeomDrawGrob() has yet to be implemented in plotly.
  If you'd like to see this geom implemented,
  Please open an issue with your example code at
  https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues
2: In geom2trace.default(dots[[1L]][[1L]], dots[[2L]][[1L]], dots[[3L]][[1L]]) :
  geom_GeomDrawGrob() has yet to be implemented in plotly.
  If you'd like to see this geom implemented,
  Please open an issue with your example code at
  https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues
```

-could the issue be some parts of the plot that are not compatible with plotly?

**Edit #3: I narrowed down the problem**
The plots I want to display were generated using `plotly::subplot()` or a similar function. When I only plot one of the plot panels I can pass it to the first script within the `html` list correctly. However, if I e.g. take this plot that was compatible with the script so far and apply `subplot()` in order to show the plot two times stacked on each other, it will no longer be possible to display it correctly in via `shinyApp()`.

Comment: There are at least a couple of issues I can see.  First, I don't see a definition of the object `html`, which you're subsetting.  The second is that you're assigning the output of the subset of `html` to the object `plot`, but you're never printing it.  If you take out `plot <-`, assuming that `html` is a vector that contains plotly output, should work.  Without the data and code it's hard to know for sure.

Comment: @DaveArmstrong Shouldn't  `plot <- ` still silently return plot, thereby printing it? or no?

Comment: @SmokeyShakers Yes, you're right.  I made a working example of something like what you'd want to do.  I'll post it in an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Somehow the data to plot gets lost on the way; I have to plot from within the `server <-...` function like this:

```
server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$filter_degree <- renderUI({
    radioButtons("rd", "Select Sample", choices = str_replace(files, ".xy", ""),
                 selected = "AH1Y")
  })
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    plot(results[[which(str_replace(files, ".xy", "") == input$rd)]], wavelength = "Cu", interactive = TRUE, mode = "both",
         main = str_replace(files[[i]], ".xy", ""))
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of using `ggplotly` to make two plots that get saved in a list and then called by a selector.

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("plots", "Plots", c("plot1", "plot2"))
  ),
  mainPanel(
    plotlyOutput("plot")
  )
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  p1 <- ggplot(iris, aes_string(x="Sepal.Length", y="Petal.Length")) +
    geom_point()  
  p1 <- ggplotly(p1)
  p2 <- ggplot(iris, aes_string(x="Sepal.Width", y="Petal.Width")) +
    geom_point() 
  p2 <- ggplotly(p2)
  plots <- list("plot1" = p1, "plot2" = p2)
  
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    out <- plots[[input$plots]]
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```